# WCF service authentication using both x.509 certificates and Username token

Tags: wcf, ws-security

I am new to WCF. I have a requirement to expose a WCF service that will validate the callers in two ways:

1. Clients should have a valid x.509 certificate that matches the server's version. The server should verify and understand that the caller is a valid client.
2. Also, the clients should supply username/password to the service. The service should look up in a custom SQL data store (NOT Membership DB) and authorize the client as per the role corresponding to the credentials supplied.

What would be the best way to design / approach the goal?